# Whole File System is not getting open in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, filesystem, system, apt-file

[file system is only loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdyRB.png)

Most Of the time when I try to open the file system , it does not get open and only try to load it till I turn off the computer or restart the computer.
I should mention it that this problem started to occur since when I create the soft link for one of my folder, I do not know this problem is actually occur because of creating soft link.
I have two disks in my system one is SSD of 128 GB and other is HDD of 1 TB.

Comment: You cannot create soft links between 2 separate drives.

Comment: @user68186 ok thanks